# unordered_map collision with buckets

Tags: c++11, data-structures, hashtable

I am working with the unordered_map library in C++11 and I am a bit confused about how buckets work. It is clear to me that they do not work as I thought they would, per the documents on the cplusplus website.

I expected that the keys in my pairs would be hashed into the same bucket. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  unordered_map<string, string> map;
  map.emplace("abc", "bca");
  map.emplace("abc", "bac");
  cout << map.bucket_size(map.bucket("abc")) << endl;
  cout << map.bucket_count() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My expectation here was that the output would be

```
2
1
```

However, it was

```
1
2
```

I understand that what was output is much more ideal than my expectation, and having as little chaining as possible is the goal, but for my purposes I want this chaining and collision to happen so that I can carry out the computations I need to for my program. Am I missing the step to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things come up - one is that you're putting the same key in twice. What ends up happening is that the second emplace actually fails because with any of the map data structures, you only get one value per key. If you look, you'll find that the bucket containing "abc" has the value of "bca" to go with it.

As to bucket_count, there's no guarantee that it be any particular value and it's likely implementation defined. It could, for instance, be that your implementation always creates at least 2 buckets if it creates any. It could also have created the second bucket on insert of the second item before deciding that the item is discarded.

Comment: What I am trying to do is use the data structure to chain together words which are equal when sorted. For example, I want "ate" and "eat" to collide at "aet." Should I just keep the keys as sorted words and make the values vectors that I add to?

Comment: @TrueAzure, it sounds like you may want a multimap (with the key being the sorted value) rather than a map. It's probably easier than trying to do a two level (map, vector) approach.

Comment: I was able to do it with the vector, but it's too slow. I'm trying to do this on a dictionary text file of 100k words in less than .2s on my school's lab server. The vector implementation is taking give or take .3s. Isn't map implemented as a red-black tree?

Comment: Yes map uses red/black generally, while unordered_map uses hashes. They both only allow one entry per index, unlike multimap. Pax's suggestion is to build a hybrid container with a map or unordered map with a payload of a vector or list of the values you want to store at that index. You still get the benefit of the look-up but then have to process the list of objects you stored at that index.
If you are inserting a lot of objects and can't control their order or count, list may give better performance than vector, though reading back the list will be slower and ram usage generally higher.